# How to set images in 3 diferent imageview in adapter list and upload it

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, image-uploading, android-adapter

I am facing a problem in which i have to set images into 3 different `imageview` and upload it,since i have to show `imageview` in adapter list i am unable to call **`onActivityRessult`** in Adapter class due to which i am unable to get id of `imageview`

Tried to call `onActivityResult` in activity class but the id of `imageviews` are coming from adapter list

[image: screenshot]

when i click on add button it opens a dialog to select image from camera or gallery and then it should be able to set in `imageviews`

**After Editing:**
**UploadAdapter.java**

```
public class UploadAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UploadAdapter.UploadViewHolder> {

    private Callback mCallback;
    private Context ctx;
    private List<UploadModelClass> uploadModelClassList;

    public interface Callback {
        void showPictureDialog();
        void uploadMultipart();
    }

    public UploadAdapter(Context ctx, List<UploadModelClass> uploadModelClassList,Callback callback) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.uploadModelClassList = uploadModelClassList;
        this.mCallback = callback;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UploadViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_upload_list,null);
        return new UploadViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UploadViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.txtv_item_code.setText(uploadModelClassList.get(position).getItem_code());
        holder.txtv_item_name.setText(uploadModelClassList.get(position).getItem_name());

        holder.txtv_item_choose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mCallback.showPictureDialog();

            }
        });

        holder.txtv_item_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCallback.uploadMultipart();
            }
        });


        if(position %2 == 1)
        {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

        }
        else
        {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#dddddd"));

        }

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return uploadModelClassList.size();
    }

    public class UploadViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageviewUpload,imageviewUpload2;
        TextView txtv_item_code,txtv_item_name,txtv_item_choose,txtv_item_image;


        public UploadViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtv_item_code=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtv_layoutUploadList_item_code);
            txtv_item_name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtv_layoutUploadList_name);
            txtv_item_choose=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtv_layoutUploadList_choose);
            txtv_item_image=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtv_layoutUploadList_image);
            imageviewUpload=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_layoutUploadList1);
            imageviewUpload2=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_layoutUploadList2);

        }
    }
}
```

**After Editing:UploadActivity**

```
public class UploadActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements UploadAdapter.Callback {

    UploadAdapter uploadAdapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView_upload;
    ArrayList<UploadModelClass> uploadModelClassArrayList;

    private int GALLERY = 1, CAMERA = 2,GALLERY2 = 3;
    Uri filePath;
    private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY = "/abcipl";

    ImageView imageView,imageView2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        requestMultiplePermissions();

       // ProductAdapter productAdapter=new ProductAdapter();
        uploadModelClassArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView_upload = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_upload_activity);


      /*  imageView=findViewById(R.id.testttt);
        imageView2=findViewById(R.id.testttt2);*/


        uploadModelClassArrayList.add(new UploadModelClass("123445","Bulb"));
        uploadModelClassArrayList.add(new UploadModelClass("123445","Bulb"));
        uploadModelClassArrayList.add(new UploadModelClass("123445","Bulb"));
        uploadModelClassArrayList.add(new UploadModelClass("123445","Bulb"));


        recyclerView_upload.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        uploadAdapter = new UploadAdapter(this, uploadModelClassArrayList,UploadActivity.this);
        recyclerView_upload.setAdapter(uploadAdapter);

    }

    private void  requestMultiplePermissions(){
        Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermissions(
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                        // check if all permissions are granted
                        if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All permissions are granted by user!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        // check for permanent denial of any permission
                        if (report.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied()) {
                            // show alert dialog navigating to Settings
                            //openSettingsDialog();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                        token.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).
                withErrorListener(new PermissionRequestErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onError(DexterError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some Error! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .onSameThread()
                .check();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        onBackPressed();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == this.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
            if (data != null) {
                filePath = data.getData();
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(UploadActivity.this.getContentResolver(), filePath);
                    String path = saveImage(bitmap);
                    Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //imageviewUpload.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        }

       else if (requestCode == GALLERY2) {
            if (data != null) {
                filePath = data.getData();
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(UploadActivity.this.getContentResolver(), filePath);
                    String path = saveImage(bitmap);
                    Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //imageviewUpload.setImageBitmap(bitmap);



                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        }


        else if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
           // imageviewUpload.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            //imageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            saveImage(thumbnail);
            Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public String saveImage(Bitmap myBitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
        File wallpaperDirectory = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY);
        // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
        if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists()) {
            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
        }

        try {
            File f = new File(wallpaperDirectory, Calendar.getInstance()
                    .getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg");
            f.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(UploadActivity.this,
                    new String[]{f.getPath()},
                    new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);
            fo.close();
            Log.d("TAG", "File Saved::---&gt;" + f.getAbsolutePath());

            return f.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }



    @Override
    public void showPictureDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder pictureDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        pictureDialog.setTitle("Select Action");
        String[] pictureDialogItems = {
                "Select photo from gallery",
                "Capture photo from camera" };
        pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                            case 0:
                                choosePhotoFromGallery();
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                takePhotoFromCamera();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
        pictureDialog.show();

    }

    /*
     * This is the method responsible for image upload
     * We need the full image path and the name for the image in this method
     * */
    @Override
    public void uploadMultipart() {
        //getting name for the image
        // String name = editTextImgName.getText().toString().trim();

        //getting the actual path of the image
        String path = getPath(filePath);

        //Uploading code
        try {
            String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            //Creating a multi part request
            new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, Constants.UPLOAD_URL)
                    .addFileToUpload(path, "image") //Adding file
                    //.addParameter("name", name) //Adding text parameter to the request
                    .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                    .setMaxRetries(2)
                    .startUpload(); //Starting the upload

        } catch (Exception exc) {
            Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    //method to get the file path from uri
    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
        document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        cursor.close();

        cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        cursor.close();

        return path;
    }

    public void choosePhotoFromGallery() {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY);
    }

    private void takePhotoFromCamera() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA);
    }
}
```

**layout_upload_list.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layoutUploadList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="5">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtv_layoutUploadList_item_code"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Item Code"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtv_layoutUploadList_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Item Name"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"

            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtv_layoutUploadList_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Status"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_layoutUploadList1"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="@color/monsoon"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_layoutUploadList2"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="@color/monsoon"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_layoutUploadList3"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="@color/monsoon"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtv_layoutUploadList_choose"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_add_blue"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            />

        <!--<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_layoutUploadList"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/monsoon"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            />-->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtv_layoutUploadList_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_upload_blue"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Instead of launching `showPictureDialog` from adapter, launch it from activity using callbacks. Your adapter shouldn't do these kind of work. In fact try to avoid sending `context` to the adapter. Get photo uri in activity and then update adapter using `notifyDataSetChanged` or `notifyItemChangedAt`.

Comment: `uploadMultipart` should also be moved to activity. Adapter should only worry about how it is supposed to render the item and transfer its interactions to the activity.

Comment: can you post some code how to do this @Ranjan

Comment: i have implemented as above...but in onActivityResult in UploadActivity.java where i have to set image in imageview.......how to get id of imageview which is in adapter class in my uploadActivity.java

Comment: i have edited the above code @Ranjan

Comment: Comment answer related things below the answer not in the question. Also never change the code you posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how `Adapter` should communicate with the `Activity`.

```
public class SomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements SomeAdapter.Callback {
    ArrayList<String> imagesUris1 = new ArrayList();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.layout_file);

        SomeAdapter adapter = new SomeAdpter(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        //calling saveImage()
    }

    public String saveImage(Bitmap myBitmap) {
        try{
            //...getting file uri
            imageUris1.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
            adapter.setFirstImageUris(imageUris1);
            return f.getAbsolutePath(); //Ignored
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

    //..Other activity related stuff

    @Override
    void showImageDialog() {
      //Open gallary or camera from here
    }
}

public class SomeAdpter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SomeAdapter.SomeHolder> {
  Callback callback;
  ArrayList<String> firstImageUris, secondImageUris, thirdImagesUris = new ArrayList();

  public SomeAdapter(Callback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
    firstImageUris = new ArrayList();
    for(int i=0; i<uploadModelClassList.size(); i++) {
        firstImageUris.add("");
    }
  }
  //Adapter related methods, call callback.showImageDialog() in onBindViewHolder
  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UploadViewHolder holder, final int position) {
      //Use uri arraylist to show image in imageview.
      holder.imageviewUpload.setImageURI(firstImageUris.get(position));
  }

  public void setFirstImageUris(ArrayList<String> imagesUris) {
      this.firstImageUris = imageUris;
      notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
  //Similar methods to store 2nd and 3rd image uris.

  public interface Callback {
    void showImageDialog();
  }
}
```

You are ignoring the `absoluteFilePath` of the image you saved. Make an `arraylist` in `activity` to save it and pass it to `adapter`. Activity doesn't have to know the id of `imageview`, it just have to pass the data to adapter. Adapter should update itself with `notifyDataSetChanged`. I've added some dummy code to help you out with first image, you'll have to do the same for 2nd and 3rd place images.

You have to write your own logic for handling image index and uri lists. Adding some sample code to help you a bit.

```
//Initialize uri lists with uploadModelClassArrayList so that they have same size
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            uploadModelClassArrayList.add(new UploadModelClass("123445", "Bulb"));
            imagesUris1.add("");
            imagesUris2.add("");
            imagesUris3.add("");
        }

//Pass lists to the adapter constructor
    uploadAdapter = new UploadAdapter(this, uploadModelClassArrayList, imagesUris1,
                imagesUris2, imagesUris3, UploadActivity.this);

//Initialize adapter lists
    public UploadAdapter(Context ctx, List<UploadModelClass> uploadModelClassList,
                ArrayList<String> firstImagelist, ArrayList<String> secondImagelist,
                ArrayList<String> thirdImagelist, Callback callback) {
            this.ctx = ctx;
            this.firstImageUris = firstImagelist;
            this.secondImageUris = secondImagelist;
            this.thirdImagesUris = thirdImagelist;
            this.uploadModelClassList = uploadModelClassList;
            this.mCallback = callback;
    }
```

Comment: //Use uri arraylist to show image in imageview...............this part i did'nt understand how to save image in on bindview holder

Comment: You have already saved image on the device in activity and got its uri and passed it to adapter. Now just have to give uri to image view in `onBindViewholder`. Check the updated code.

Comment: applicatrion is crashing when i try to open the actiivty.......because first it is setting the adapter ......since i havenn't selected the image yet it is getting null java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference.......

Comment: You shouldn't have got NPE because we have initialized the `firstImageUris` in the adapter, but you definitely will get IndexOutOfBound because your arraylist doesn't contain any item.

Comment: Initialize uri arraylist in your adapter's constructor `firstImageUris = new ArrayList(uploadModelClassList.size());`

Comment: after initializing firstImageUris = new ArrayList(uploadModelClassList.size());........now i am getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: That means your `uploadModelClassList.size = 0`. Are you new to Java as well? It shouldn't be empty since you added 4 items into it `uploadModelClassArrayList.add(new UploadModelClass("123445","Bulb"));`.

Comment: my uploadModelClassList.size = 4 but my firstImageUris has size 0 on initializing.Yeah i don't have much hand on practices on java,I have started to learn java and android. I think the issue is in this line holder.imageviewUpload.setImageURI(Uri.parse(firstImageUris.get(position))); adapter is setting the data before actually picking the image.

Comment: My mistake, I thought initializing with initial capacity will work but it does something else, besides all the items would be null so you would've got NPE next. I have added a workaround which adds new items to the list. This is not the best approach though.

Comment: Now i am getting this java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1==>
holder.imageviewUpload.setImageURI(Uri.parse(firstImageUris.get(position)));
        Log.d("dsdsd",firstImageUris.get(position));

when i check the log value it is showing path of image====> D/dsdsd: /storage/emulated/0/abc/1549282117881.jpg

Comment: Of course, because when you set `imageUris1.add(f.getAbsolutePath());`, your imageUris1 have a single value in it and you pass it to adapter which replaces the list with size 4. These are all Java related problems and also not part of this question. You have to write your own logic to deal with these issues. Also you have to write a lot of logic to handle 2nd and 3rd image and I can't keep helping you write the whole code. That being said I think you should initialize all the arraylist in activity and pass them to adapter. Adding a sample code. Good Luck!

Comment: thank u brother...you helped me a lot.... i didn't know a lot of concepts....from your guidance i came to know a lot of things.....Thanks Again..!!!